# RGB Mapping for each Object

Tags: javascript

I have javascript object which contains 8 objects. each object will have its corresponding color information. Is there a way to map each object with a RGB color?

**input**

```
myData[{a:29},{a:17},{a:26},a{19},a{18},a{40},a{89},a{14}];
```

**output:**

```
myData[{a:29, color:#RGB},{a:17, color:#RGB},....];
```

Comment: what do you want #RGB to be?

Comment: RGB is color information. What I want actually is just to a assign a color to each object.

Comment: Give a concrete example. What value do you want where you wrote #RGB?

Comment: the max RGB is FFF and lowest is 000. I want to divide` (FFF-000/8)` and assing a color to its corresponding object

Comment: In order to make it simple. `myData[{a:29, color:'red'}, {a:17, color:'yellow'}, ..etc];` Since the number of objects is dynamic, therefore I should come up a modular way to handle it rather than hard coded color values.

Comment: What logic mandates that 29 should be 'red' and 17 'yellow'?

Comment: Smallest value coloser to white, highest value coloser to black.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77743/discussion-between-amit-and-ilyas-uyanik).

Comment: There is proxy prohibits to use chat feature :-(

Comment: *"Smallest value coloser to white, highest value coloser to black"* - that actually only makes sense in a gray scale. What determines the values for R, G and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
function insertAt(ary, item, at) {
  ary.splice(at, 0, item);
}

function addColors(data, hue) {
  var dataWithColors = [];
  var highest = data[0].a;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].a > highest) {
      highest = data[i].a;
    }
  }
  var lowest = data[0].a;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].a < lowest) {
      lowest = data[i].a;
    }
  }
  var hueIndexes = {red: 0, green: 1, blue: 2};
  var range = highest - lowest;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i].a;
    var absInRange = value - lowest;
    var shade = Math.round(0xff - (0xff * absInRange / range));
    var subStr = shade.toString(16);
    if (subStr.length == 1) {
      subStr = "0" + subStr;
    }
    var color = ["00", "00"];
    insertAt(color, subStr, hueIndexes[hue]);
    var str = "#" + color.join("");
    dataWithColors.push({a: value, color: str});
      // (Alternative: eg https://lodash.com/docs#assign .)
  }
  return dataWithColors;
}

var sample = [{a:29},{a:17},{a:26},{a:19},{a:18},{a:40},{a:89},{a:14}];
var sampleWithColors = addColors(sample, "green");

console.dir(sampleWithColors);
/* [
  {a: 29, color: "#00cc00"},
  {a: 17, color: "#00f500"},
  {a: 26, color: "#00d600"},
  {a: 19, color: "#00ee00"},
  {a: 18, color: "#00f100"},
  {a: 40, color: "#00a700"},
  {a: 89, color: "#000000"},
  {a: 14, color: "#00ff00"}
] */
```

Comment: I don't understand why the calculated value is being used to represent the value for green. The question doesn't state that the value should be used for green only. Besides, running your code, `data[4].color` is `"#00e00"`, which is - if not invalid - at least an unusual RGB representation.

Comment: From what Ilyas wrote in existing comments it seemed as if he didn't care about the exact hue.
"What I want actually is just to a assign a color to each object."
"In order to make it simple. myData[{a:29, color:'red'}, {a:17, color:'yellow'}, ..etc]; Since the number of objects is dynamic, therefore I should come up a modular way to handle it rather than hard coded color values."

Comment: Then yes, I think you answer is a valid approach.

Comment: If the number of objects is much larger than the set of objects in the original question, there won't be much difference between the greens (or reds/blues/greys). In that case I'd consider some JS lib eg https://github.com/brehaut/color-js and use a range of hues, so that the highest values have shades of yellow, the medium values have shades of orange/red/violet, and the lowest values have shades of blue (for example).

Comment: The above solution assigns colors based on the actual value - if there are two objects with the same value, they will get the same color shade.  That seems to be what Ilyas wanted: "each object will have its corresponding color information". Small values get brighter color shades, higher values get darker color shades.

Answer (score 1):

A handy fact to know is that the colors #000 through #fff can be represented by the numbers 0 through 4095 in hexidecimal. With that in mind, we can write a function to generate a color in the range.

Here's one I wrote that requires the current index and the max number of segments:

```
function getColor(current, max) {
  var num = ((4095 / max * current) >>> 0).toString(16);
  while (num.length < 3) {
    num = "0" + num;
  }
  return "#"+num;
}
```

And here you can see it in action (type larger numbers in the text box to see how it would handle arrays of varying size).

```js
updateOutput();
document.getElementById("input").onkeyup = updateOutput;

function updateOutput() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var data = new Array(+document.getElementById("input").value);
  var len = data.length;
  output.innerHTML = "";
  while (len--) {
    var color = getColor(len, data.length);
    output.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<li style='color:#" + color + "'>(#" + color + ")</li>");
  }
}

function getColor(current, max) {
  var num = ((4095 / max * current) >>> 0).toString(16);
  while (num.length < 3) {
    num = "0" + num;
  }
  return num;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="8" />
<ol id="output" />
```

Notice that the lower numbers are generally closer to black and the higher numbers are generally closer to white, but the colors in between can vary greatly depending on the number of divisions. For example, when you split 4095 into 15 segments, they all turn out to be shades of gray!

Do keep in mind that this approach places an arbitrary size limit of 4095 on the length of your array.